# New file has unexpected '\r' at the end of the filename

Tags: shell-script, sed

whiteLabels.css contains:

```
/*
abcd
*/
```

I want to create a new file new1.css

which contains only

```
abcd
```

(without `/*`)

this statement removes it

```
sed 's|[/*]||g' whiteLabels.css > new1.css
```

but instead of `new1.css` I get `new1.css`. as seen in the image attached

[image]

On exploring I find it is of the type `new1.css\r` in directory

What changes should I make , what seems to be the issue?

Comment: Is that `sed` statement in a script or are you entering it by hand at the command line?

Answer (score 3):

You probably had that command pass through Windows at some point, so it now has the `\r\n` line ending, but *nix only looks for `\n` so leaves the `\r`.  Assuming that is in a script you can use `dos2unix` on it to remove the extra `\r` characters.